# Get Element Window Position From Within Floating Div

Tags: javascript

Normally to get the window position of any element I use:

```
while(el) {
    x += el.offsetLeft;
    y += el.offsetTop;
    el = el.offsetParent;
}
```

However, I am running into a problem when the element is within a floating div.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="floatLeft" style="float: left; width: 20%;"></div>
    <div id="floatRight" style="float: right; width: 80%;">
        <div>I want to find the window pos of this</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the situation above where the element is nested inside a floating div, it returns the offset only from the edge of the right div. Of course this is a simplified example, in a real world situation, the right div would have multiple nested elements etc. None the less, how do I modify the javascript I am using to consider floating elements?

EDIT: The problem was actually in the way I was positioning an absolute element as opposed to having anything to do with the offsets of floating divs. This question is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try use jQuery:

```
while(el) {
    x += $(el).offset().left;
    y += $(el).offset().top;
}
```